# Disable watch node_modules with Angular cli

Tags: angular, webpack

I get the famous error `Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch 'frontend/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/platform-browser.d.ts.__ivy_ngcc_bak'`.

The problem I think is webpack is watching node_modules files.

I use linux, I have `fs.inotify.max_user_watches=1048576` and the problem persists.

When I remove node_modules and rebuild el project, it works fine for a few hours...

Any way to exclude node_modules for watching in angular project?

Answer (score 1):

I tracked down this problem to copying of assets in `angular.json` by using wildcard in glob:

```
{
 "input": "../",
 "glob": "*.md",
 "output": "./assets/"
}
```

in this case angular watches everything under parent directory (including `node_modules`). What worked for me was either not using wildcards:

```
{
 "input": "../",
 "glob": "README.md",
 "output": "./assets/"
}
```

or in `prebuild` (or `prestart`) step copying necessary files to ./tmp directory and then using:

```
{
 "input": "./tmp/",
 "glob": "*.md",
 "output": "./assets/"
}
```

Of course in the latter case I cannot run simply `ng serve`, but I need to have something like:

```
"start": "ng serve",
"prebuild":"mkdir -p tmp && cp ../*.md ./tmp/",
"prestart":"npm run prebuild",
```

in my `package.json` and use: `npm run start` instead

Also, it looks like this problem is particular to **Linux**. No problems on **Windows**.